# Clarify what the Yes/No responses do in Careers reply interface

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

I recently received a careers email asking me to consider a role advertised on Stack Overflow Careers. It looked good but there were a few things that made it unsuitable, so I was minded to reply to see if there is any wiggle-room.

Now there probably isn't any wiggle room, but interestingly the Careers message interface *reduces* the wiggle room itself. Before I can reply I must answer a very binary question using one of two buttons:

- YES I AM INTERESTED
- NOT INTERESTED

I leaned towards "no", and was soon made aware this sent a message to the employer on my behalf before I was ready - oops! UI affordance seems lacking here: buttons should not have unexpected actions.

The message conversion (presumably also what the employer sees) records me as saying that I am `NOT INTERESTED [red warning]`, whereas I would say my thoughts on the matter are more subtle than that. No harm done, but possibly worth reflecting on.

I then replied summarising my thoughts in text, and I tend to take a while to compose messages, so as to fully consider how it might be read. Thus if the employer is using Stack Overflow Careers when I clicked on the above "No", the delay between their receiving `NOT INTERESTED [red warning]` and a polite email thanking them for their time and interest can rather look like a brusque rebuttal.

To fix this, I wonder if these items might be considered:

- Make it clearer what the two buttons do. "Yes" shares details, "no" does not. No message is sent unless the UI makes it clear.
- Reduce the shouty caps
- Send the interested/not interested classification at the same time as a manual message. This could be done by rewording the buttons as radio icons, and displaying the reply interface straight away. (If people choose to leave the message blank, that's up to them, of course).

Comment: +1, I've felt the same way every time I rejected a message

Comment: That edit is OK @random, though delaying the classification email until the manual email is sent is also an important part of it.

Comment: Thought about adding two focus points, but then that would be too clunky a title

Comment: Yeah, I had the problem @random! No matter, it's all in the body.

Comment: "Reduce the shouty caps" -> yes, no caps please! We don't say "no" to a job offer shouting.

Comment: Why isn't there a third option? Something along the lines of "I'm not interested right now, but I'd like to keep communication open"

Comment: @Shotgun: it's not what I'm asking for, but I'd not be opposed to it. At the moment, it's just about making the UX more obvious in its effects.

Answer (score 57):

As someone who didn't know that's how it worked I'm shocked.

I assumed that pressing not interested quietly closed the message stream without shouting "NOT INTERESTED" at the would be employer.

If a message is going to be sent to the employer then I should have full control over that content. Perhaps I'm just not interested right at this moment but would like to hear from the employer again in 6 months.

Comment: As far as I know, using the "No" button does not prohibit the employer from sending another message in six months. Or are you suggesting there should be a third option, maybe "Not right now"?

Comment: Maybe the suggestion is to state that, if the interface allowed it.

Comment: @halfer +1 for "not right now"

Comment: Yeah also - not this job, but I like this company would be a good option.

Comment: @halfer: It may not prevent them from sending another message 6 months later, but having got a shouty NO from you already, they might well decided not to send another message by themselves, which I think is the concern here.

Comment: I think there's room for improving the behavior here generally, but I'm not in favor of adding a "not right now" option. What does "right now" mean? Everyone will have their own definition, so we're not really gaining anything. I think the 'not right now' case is solved by "not interested" + a message saying why.

Comment: @Laura I think the concern is more around changing the negative aspects of the not interested, and allowing a message to be composed at the time of the not interested.

Answer (score 6):

I don't believe that the "NOT INTERESTED" message can sound bad to the employer. You are just another unknown person that he found searching profiles. No strings attached.

However, it would be nice to send a manual message *along with* the response so you could add why you are declining the specific opportunity and trying to open a door for another one. Sending a message *after* the Yes/No answer may throw it in a limbo. The manual message could replace the automatic message.

But the best feature would be to add a "Not right now" button as you've suggested in a [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298191/1476885). The UI lacks the option to tell the employer "I'm busy right now, call me later, ok?" (in 3-6 months). If you are worried about closed doors, this would let it open.

Comment: There _is_ an option for a manual message. Part of my suggestion was that any automatic messages sent by the yes/no buttons should wait until the manual message is sent, so they can be read together.

Comment: You're right. Edited to let it clear. Maybe would be better to *replace* the automatic message by the manual message. The employer would receive something like: "Not interested - Reason: <manual message>"

Answer (score 4):

It seemed pretty obvious to me that the two buttons would send a response back to the person making the contact, one of which ("interested") which meant to continue the conversation, and the other ("not interested") which meant to not have a conversation.

Just my two cents, but it's perfect (for me) just the way it is.

Comment: OK, fair enough. Do you have any feedback as to delaying the classification message until the main body of the message is sent? Would this harm the UI experience in any way?

Comment: I think it works really well (at least for me!) now. The workflow is pretty straightforward: An employer sees your stuff and sends you a message (so you know the employer is interested).  You can read the description, and indicate if you (a) wish to continue the conversation, (b) don't wish to continue the conversation.  In my experience, clicking "interested" results in an almost immediate email suggesting times for a converstation.  At that point you've got direct email and phone contact to the person wishing to talk to you.  I can't imagine anything more smooth.  Just IMHO!!

Comment: Thanks for your feedback that you like it as it is. But do you think my suggestion about merging the two email send-times be worse? I see it as better for the reason stated, without harming the UX.

Comment: `In my experience, clicking "interested" results in an almost immediate email suggesting times for a converstation.` but that's exactly what you don't want if you aren't interested *right now*. So now exchanging more emails to state that you don't want a conversation at the moment is just wasting everybody's time.