# Developer Jobs messaging button for "I Might Be Interested"

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, jobs-messages

Currently, for Developer Jobs inbox messages from prospective employers, there is a green button for *"I'm Interested"* and a red button for *"I'm Not Interested"* ... but sometimes, interest is not so clear cut.

How about a button for something in between - *"I Might Be Interested"* ...?

Sometimes, it is difficult to fully assess whether an opportunity is of interest or not.

It might be, to both parties, but more discussion could be required. Or, maybe the timing isn't right, but interest in the company is significant. *I'm Interested* in this case, seems potentially misleading, while *"I'm Not Interested"* seems too strong a rejection.

Without the middle ground, a user pathway seems to be missing.

<sub>This is potentially a furthering of the discussion found in [Clarify what the Yes/No responses do in Careers reply interface](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298112/clarify-what-the-yes-no-responses-do-in-careers-reply-interface).</sub>

[image: 3 buttons - I am, I Might Be, and I'm Not Interested]

Comment: Just press "I'm interested" and send the employer a message indicating how you feel.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson Yep. But the question is more about formalizing the UX for **hot** (interested), **warm** (maybe), and **cold** (not).  Without the middle ground, a user pathway seems to be missing.

Comment: What exactly is a potential employer supposed to do with a lukewarm "I might be interested", though? The binary choice seems correct here. Either you're interested (which doesn't imply any sort of commitment, just that you want to learn more) or not. The "I might" bit is implied anyway - of 100 people who hit "I'm interested" only one is going to end up with the job, if at all.

Comment: @jacefarm I see that as a relatively fine distinction. In both your "hot" and "warm" scenarios the practical outcome is the same: you want to continue a dialogue with the employer. The "interested" terminology is deliberately non-committal.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Yes, that's true. That makes sense.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson Yes, makes sense, but a user seeking a job will want to make clear and fine distinctions with prospective employers, and not give false impressions.  "I'm Interested" seems overloaded when the job is not of interest, but a connection with the employer is.  I hear you though.