# Provide 3rd option to clarify job specs when replying on job messages

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, stack-overflow-jobs, jobs-messages

I keep receiving some job messages, however, most of the times recruiters doesn't clarify enough details in their initial message (such as type of job: permanent or contract, or location), therefore, it is not simple for me to choose one of two available options: *I'm interested* or *I'm not interested*. I could be interested if I could clarify these details, but at the same time, I don't want to reject the message without knowing the details. I'm aware that I can still reply after choosing that *I'm not interested*, but still I don't feel it's the right way. This is not the first time I am confused what to choose, as there is no way to simply reply to the message directly.

I think the solution would be to provide the 3rd option such as *I need more details*, clarification or some other similar, neutral-based option.

---

Here is the example (edited out for privacy reason):

[image: Stack Overflow, job message]

Comment: [This downvoted question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359419/developer-jobs-messaging-button-for-i-might-be-interested) was in the list of "Related" questions. The comments seem to suggest that if you are even slightly interested, you should chose **_"I'm interested"_**, and ask the potential employer for clarifications.

Comment: I'd rather we kept the two existing options but were allowed to send message back without selecting one

Comment: If you're interested in finding out more, then, well, I guess you're interested right?

Comment: I'm not really interested, as I've got a job, I'm rather just curious about the details to find out more.

Answer (score 1):

> "I wanted to discuss your experience and the possible opportunity I have here. Can you advise when we can discuss this in more detail?"

If you're interested in discussing the possible opportunity in more detail, then *I'm interested* seems appropriate. Needing more information would fit under this category for me.

If you're not interested in discussing the opportunity, given what you know now, then *I'm Not Interested* would be the one to choose.

I don't see anywhere where you're being asked to commit to being interested in the job. I read it as simply, "I'm interested in learning more."

Comment: In my case I'm only _interested_ when it's a contract role, however it doesn't say what type of role it is, but based on my experience so far, it is likely to be a permanent position which makes me think that I am _not interested_. But without clarification, it is just my guess. Secondly, it doesn't clarify location or salary, on which my reply also depends, which makes me feel like I need to clarify the job specs first. So these two options for me is just like a random choice at the end.

Answer (score -3):

As [BLT mentioned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/360924/920295), if you are interested in continuing the conversation (even if it's just to ask questions) you should choose "I'm interested", on your response, ask what you need to know.

When replying "I'm interested", you're just saying that you're interested in talking with the recruiter (which is the case if you want to know details), it doesn't mean "I'm interested in this job, let's schedule an interview".

I'll bring this discussion internally, we may want to adjust the copy there.